# Explain - Formula to curve through a control point

Tags: math, canvas, formula, bezier, quadratic

I have a question regarding formula curving through a control point.
As you know, HTML Canvas has `quadraticCurveTo(x1, y1, x2, y2)` with `x1 and x2` being the control point.

However when you try to draw a stroke using it, the stroke will never touch the control point.

So we have this formula:

```
x1 = xt * 2 - (x0 + x2) / 2;
y1 = yt * 2 - (y0 + y2) / 2;
```

`(xt, yt)` = the point you want to curve through. `t` for tangent as it is 90 degrees perpendicular at that point.

This recalculates the control point position.

I got this formula from a book, however the book doesn't explain how it is been derived. I tried google around but in vain.

Anyone knows how this formula is derived?

Thanks,
Venn.

Comment: This is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711707/draw-a-quadratic-bezier-curve-through-three-given-points for anyone wondering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quadratic Bezier curve is described by equations:

`x(t) = x0 * (1-t)^2 + 2 * x1 * t * (1 - t) + x2 * t^2`  (and similar for y(t)).

If we apply parameter value t = 1/2 (in some way - middle of the curve), we will get your formula:

`x(t=1/2) = xt = x0 * 1/4 + 2 * x1 * 1/4 + x2 * 1/4`

then

`x1/2 = xt - (x0 + x2)/4`

`x1 = 2 * xt - (x0 + x2)/2`

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [Spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29). More to the point, it appears that they are using a [Bezier Curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it how x1 = xt * 2 - (x0 + x2) / 2;
y1 = yt * 2 - (y0 + y2) / 2; is being derived.

Comment: @Vennsoh: Edited my answer, I believe that they are using a quadratic Bezier Curve. See the derivation in the linked wiki article.