# Curve Animation in Swift and UIKit - Parabolic Movement from starting/endingpoint

Tags: ios, swift, math, uikit

I'm still a beginner to UIKit but i'm working on something and I created a dynamic framework to spawn monsters and have them go along pre-determined waypoints from a config file.

So for a given monster, I started setting simple waypoints like go across the screen, or go along a particular path based on (x,y) coordinates. Each path has a series of waypoints, and the monster follows it, then reverses.

This works great, but now I want to have the monsters jump up along an arc (so something quadratic/parabolic). So I thought to myself this is fairly easy, simply create the waypoints to represent an arc, and i'll achieve this.
Right now i'm simply doing

```
SKAction.MoveBy(x,y, duration)
```

Well it worked, but the animation isn't smooth because I just guessed at the waypoints, instead of using an actual mathematical parabolic function. So I did things like:

```
(5, 10),
(5, 10),
(10, 10),
(15, 10),
.. and then on the way down
(-15, -10)
..
etc
```

So I think I either need to do 2 things, which i'm unsure about:

1. Find something (website / tool / math function?) that can generate the smoother, proper set of (x,y) coordinates for arcs quickly for me so I can then input them into my config file and achieve a smooth monster jump along an arc. I don't remember this sort of math from school it's just been too long =/  .
2. Use some sort of function built into Swift that can do this for me automatically (I did some research but most of it was either old Objective-C stuff, or looked insanely complicated).

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about scene kit, but if you have a way to make your sprite travel across a Bezier path then a quadratic (not cubic) Bezier path is exactly what you need. A parabola is a quadratic curve, so it should be easy to model with a Quadratic bezier (2 end points plus a single control point.)

Comment: that's exciting and might be what i'm looking for, you should respond as an answer so I can potentially give you credit. Is setting up a quadratic bezier easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about scene kit, but if you have a way to make your sprite travel across a Bezier path then a quadratic (not cubic) Bezier path is exactly what you need. A parabola is a quadratic curve, so it should be easy to model with a Quadratic bezier (2 end points plus a single control point.)

Creating a quadratic bezier curve is trivially easy. you specify a start and end point and a control point, and the curve follows the V defined by those 3 points.

Comment: Let us know if you're able to use a bezier curve to make your monsters follow a parabolic path.

Comment: I can't figure it out actually - do you think you could help? I want it to just go on an arc, and then stop (not go back). I'll make it go back later on my own after other events fire and a timer runs out

Comment: I don't know anything about SceneKit. How do you animate a monster along a path? I can show you how to create a `UIBezierPath` or a `CGPath` in a parabolic shape, and I could show you how to animate that using `UIView` or `CAAnimation`, but not SceneKit.

Comment: Hey Duncan I think I got it I found code here that was a huge help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723031/undestanding-uibezierpath-curving-mechanism-controlpoint-and-the-curve-point thank you though you got me in the right direction :) I think I can figure this out!!