# how to draw a curve that passes three points in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

What I am going to do is to change the curve of a circle.
If I click one point in a circle and drag it to other point, that arc of the circle should be extended or contracted accordingly.
I was going to use beizer curve but there's no guarantee that the new beizer curve will pass the dragged point.
Attached is the image showing a new curve when mouse dragged which I can not solve.
can anyone help me on this matter?
I will be looking forward to your reply[image: canvas image]

Comment: why there's no guarantee? you mean when they're aligned?

Comment: I studied this material: 'https://javascript.info/bezier-curve'. when I enter three points, the new curve doesn't pass the middle point. It is just placed inside the triangle of three points. Do you have any idea how to make this pass the middle point as well? All I know is just three points coordinates.

Comment: Oh! you mean the control points! but yet given three points on the 2D space *there is* a curve fits them. Here is something might help you then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711707/draw-a-quadratic-b%C3%A9zier-curve-through-three-given-points

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I had a look at the material you gave me and followed it assuming t=0.5 it gave me the new control point ( 800, 100 ) but I still get the wrong result. Please have a look at 'https://ibb.co/K0zqLPr' and tell me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: I found a complete example that should make what you want: http://jsbin.com/ApitIxo/2/ Please, consider rewarding the original submitter here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20309900/632445

Comment: thank you. very perfect answer. (thumb up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fit circle to points

Maybe this will help.

The function at the top of the example `fitCircleToPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)` will fit a circle to 3 points.

It returns an object

```
{
   x, y,   // center of circle
   radius, // radius of circle
   CCW,    // true if circle segment is counter clockwise
}
```

If the 3 points are all on the same line then there is no circle that can fit (radius Infinity is not valid) so the function returns undefined.

```js
function fitCircleToPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
    var x, y, u;
    const slopeA = (x2 - x1) / (y1 - y2); // slope of vector from point 1 to 2
    const slopeB = (x3 - x2) / (y2 - y3); // slope of vector from point 2 to 3
    if (slopeA === slopeB)  { return } // Slopes are same thus 3 points form striaght line. No circle can fit.
    if (y1 === y2) {   // special case with points 1 and 2 have same y 
        x = ((x1 + x2) / 2);
        y = slopeB * x + (((y2 + y3) / 2) - slopeB * ((x2 + x3) / 2));  
    } else if(y2 === y3) { // special case with points 2 and 3 have same y 
        x = ((x2 + x3) / 2);
        y = slopeA * x + (((y1 + y2) / 2) - slopeA * ((x1 + x2) / 2));  
    } else {
        x = ((((y2 + y3) / 2) - slopeB * ((x2 + x3) / 2)) - (u = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - slopeA * ((x1 + x2) / 2))) / (slopeA - slopeB);
        y = slopeA * x + u;
    }
    
    return {
        x, y, 
        radius: ((x1 - x) ** 2 + (y1 - y) ** 2) ** 0.5,
        CCW: ((x3 - x1) * (y2 - y1) - (y3 - y1) * (x2 - x1)) >= 0,
    };
}


requestAnimationFrame(update);

Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false}   
function mouseEvents(e){
    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouseEvents));
var w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height, cw = w / 2, ch = h / 2;
var nearest, ox, oy, dragging, dragIdx;
const points = [10,110,200,100,400,110];
function drawPoint(x, y, rad, col = "black") {
     ctx.strokeStyle = col;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x, y, rad, 0, Math.TAU);
     ctx.stroke();
 }
function drawLines(idx, col = "black") {
     ctx.strokeStyle = col;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.lineTo(points[idx++], points[idx++]);
     ctx.lineTo(points[idx++], points[idx++]);
     ctx.lineTo(points[idx++], points[idx++]);
     ctx.stroke();
} 
function drawPoints() {
  var i = 0, x, y;
  nearest = - 1;
  var minDist = 20;
  while (i < points.length) {
     drawPoint(x = points[i++], y = points[i++], 4);
     const dist = (x - mouse.x) ** 2 + (y - mouse.y) ** 2;
     if (dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        nearest = i - 2;
     }
  }
}

function update(){
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {
        cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
        ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
    } else {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    }
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    drawPoints();
    if (nearest > -1) {
      if (mouse.button) {
        if (!dragging) {
            dragging = true;
            ox = points[nearest] - mouse.x;
            oy = points[nearest+1] - mouse.y;
            dragIdx = nearest;
        }
      } else {
          canvas.style.cursor = "move";
      }
      drawPoint(points[nearest], points[nearest + 1], 6, "red")
    }
    if (dragging) {
        if (!mouse.button) {
            dragging = false;
        } else {
            points[dragIdx] = mouse.x + ox;
            points[dragIdx + 1] = mouse.y + oy
            canvas.style.cursor = "none";
        }
    }
    
    drawLines(0, "#0002");
    const circle = fitCircleToPoints(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], points[4], points[5]);
    if (circle) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
        const ang1 = Math.atan2(points[1] - circle.y, points[0]- circle.x);
        const ang2 = Math.atan2(points[5] - circle.y, points[4]- circle.x);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, ang1, ang2, circle.CCW);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
canvas { position : absolute; top : 0px; left : 0px; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
Use mouse to move points.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could draw two curves but make sure the control points are in line so you get a smooth transition. Using [this tool](https://www.victoriakirst.com/beziertool/) I've made an example. His is however not a circle and not an ellipse.
[image]