# Cubic bezier curve that pass through 3 points

Tags: javascript, geometry, cubic-bezier

There are points:

- P0 (left-top)
- P3 (right-bottom)
- Control Point - a point that can be moved, a curve should pass through it

I need to connect them using a cubic curve, so that the end of the curve is 'approximately horizontal' and it is also possible to move the Control Point

So I put P2 on the coordinates P0.x P3.y (maybe this is the wrong decision)

Now I need to calculate P1 so that the curve passes through the Control Point

I saw a good example with a quadratic curve
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66463100/20852881

Earlier i used the quadratic curve from this example, however, it became necessary to make the end of the curve 'approximately horizontal' (for such an arrangement P0 (left-top) and P3(right-bottom))
, so I look towards the cubic curve

Comment: There is infinite number of cubic curves with described properties, so it is worth to define more limitations (now you can vary three parameters - P2.X, P1.X, P1.Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solid-js solution, based on [Article1](https://www.jointjs.com/blog/how-to-create-nice-looking-curves-in-svg-with-fixed-tangents) and mostly on [Article2](https://apoorvaj.io/cubic-bezier-through-four-points/)

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-architecture-2y5kgx

Comment: So you have used some curves rather than one?

Comment: @MBo yes, i used Catmull-Rom splines, which are described in articles, which are converted to curves, for display via svg